# What are eigenvalues/eigenfunctions of a "pointwise product" operator

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let us consider the Hilbert space $l^2([0,1])$ with inner product $<u,v>=\int_0^1 u(x)v(x)\mathrm dx$. We define a pointwise product operator $A$ as $(A\circ u)(x)=a(x)\cdot u(x)$, where "$\cdot$" denotes the scalar product, and $a$ is a bounded function. It can be verified that $A$ is a linear and self-adjoint operator. Then, there should be countable real eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ and eigenfunctions $\phi_n$ so that $(A\circ u)(x)=\sum_n \lambda_n <\phi_n,u>\phi_n(x)$. But it is not clear for me what they are.

Comment: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $\{x : a(x)=\lambda\}$ has positive measure, so typically this operator won't have any eigenvalues.

Comment: I think this operator is self-adjoint. According to the spectral theorem, "Suppose A is a compact self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space V. There is an orthonormal basis of V consisting of eigenvectors of A. Each eigenvalue is real." (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) So what does the problem come from? Is it a non-compact operator?

Comment: Your operator is not compact.